# Stop First Person Controller input from another script in Unity 3D

Tags: variables, 3d, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm using Unity 3D with unityscript for the programming.

I have a First Person Controller with the built-in script CharacterMotor.js. In that script, there is a variable declared at the top called "canControl" that is a boolean and controls whether or not the First Person Controller responds to input.

I want to be able to change that boolean from a script attached to a different object, like a cube.

Here's what I'm currently doing with the script attached to my cube:

```
#pragma strict

var stop : GameObject;

function Start () {
}

function Update () {
    stop.GetComponent("CharacterMotor").canControl = false;
}
```

I have dragged the First Person Controller object to the stop variable in the reference inspector sidebar.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Assets/test.js(15,45): BCE0019: 'canControl' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.Component'.
```

So, it looks like it's not able to reference the variable canControl in the CharacterMotor.js script for some reason.

I've looked all over and can't find what I'm doing differently. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Two small issues:

First, GetComponent always returns an object of type 'Component'. canControl is not defined in Component, it is defined in CharacterMotor. This means we need to cast its return value to a CharacterMotor.

Second, GetComponent needs to be called on the GameObject with the component that you are looking for. Easiest way I've found to do this is with FindGameObjectWithTag.

Here's the result (I'm assuming the First Person Controller has the tag 'Player'):

```
var stop : CharacterMotor;

function Start () {
    stop =(CharacterMotor)GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent("CharacterMotor");
}

function Update () {
    stop.canControl = false;
}
```

Comment: ^Since OP didn't clarify which answer was correct, for anyone stumbling upon this through the inter webs, this is the correct answer.  Though to be fair there is not reason to put that in the update loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Update () {
    stop.GetComponent("CharacterMotor");
    canControl = false;
}
```

I don't know much of Unity, but `canControl` is probable not attachable to `GetComponent`. If `canControl` is its own variable then my way should work. `GetComponent` just gets the variable. That doesn't mean it belongs to the `GetComponent` function.

I might be completely wrong though. That is just what I see when I read the code. I hope I helped.

Comment: I get an unknown identifier error for canControl. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm, the only other idea I would have is to check out the Documentation for unity and see if your answer is there.